# PySpark update values for certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm struggling a bit to identify the best way to update values in multiple columns but return the whole dataset - spark has changed rapidly and many answers seem to be outdated.

I'm running spark 2.1 on a small cluster creating a dataframe as follows:

```
df = spark.read.options(header="true",sep = '|').csv(path = 'file:///usr//local//raw_data//somefile.txt')

print df.columns 
['ID','field1','field2','field3','value'] #there are actually many more columns, this is just an example
```

I need to apply the below mapping function to field1, field2 and field3, but retain the whole dataset

```
def mappingFunction(val,dict):
    if val in dict:
        return dict(val)
    else:
        return val
```

Very simplistically I could do this like so in pandas:

```
df['field1'] = df['field1'].map(mapDict)
df['field2'] = df['field2'].map(mapDict)
df['field3'] = df['field3'].map(mapDict)
```

In pyspark, I see there's a df.rdd.map() functionality, but that seems like an "outdated" way to be approaching this - plus I already have the underlying dataset split out by columns, so I don't think I should be going back to the RDD.

I also see pyspark.sql.functions.udf(f, returnType=StringType), which seems me to what I'd like to use.

My questions are:

**Could someone confirm that defining a UDF is the right way to go in this instance?**

**If so, how do I apply a UDF to multiple columns at once?** Since I'm going to be iterating over rows, it seems like the best query design would be to apply my mapping function to all three columns at once, but I'm unsure how to do that in the context of everything else I'm doing.

**How do I go about this so that I return the full dataset, with these values updated?** All of the aggregations/manipulations I'm going to be doing after will need to use the updated column values.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably best off converting your dictionary to a `broadcast` variable, then defining a lookup `udf` and applying it to all relevant columns using a generator expression:

Let's create a dummy dataset and dictionary first:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("a",1,1,2,2),
    ("b",2,2,3,3),
    ("c",3,4,3,3)]).toDF(['ID','field1','field2','field3','value'])

myDict = {1: "y", 2: "x", 3: "z"}
```

Now we convert the dictionary to a `broadcast` variable and define the lookup `udf`:

```
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(myDict) 

def lookup(x):

  if broadcastVar.value.get(x) is None:
    return x
  else:
    return broadcastVar.value.get(x)

lookup_udf = udf(lookup)
```

Now what remains is generating a `list` of column names we'll apply our function to (everything that contains `"field"`), and putting it inside a generator expression with our `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

cols = [s for s in df.columns if "field" in s]
df.select(*(lookup_udf(col(c)).alias(c) if c in cols else c for c in df.columns)).show()
+---+------+------+------+-----+
| ID|field1|field2|field3|value|
+---+------+------+------+-----+
|  a|     y|     y|     x|    2|
|  b|     x|     x|     z|    3|
|  c|     z|     4|     z|    3|
+---+------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! Last question - I want these updates to be "permanent" - things I can then run other aggregations/calculations on. Right now your last output is just a .show() function. Would I replace that last line with:
df = df.select(*(lookup_udf(col(c)).alias(c) if c in cols else c for c in df.columns)).collect()

Comment: you can just assign your output  without `.show()` at the end such as `df1 = df.select(..`, I ended with `.show()` to print how the data looks after the transformation. Don't use `collect()` at the end, that will bring the data into the driver node.

Comment: Duh - I knew that one. Thanks!